# Pager-Adapter does not show data on first call

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager

I have a PagerAdapter that for some reason does not show the data the first time it's created! It only shows on second creation..

This is the PagerAdapter:

```
class ViewPagerAdapter() : PagerAdapter() {
lateinit var context: Context
lateinit var data: Data

constructor(context: Context?, data: Data) : this() {
    this.context = context!!
    this.data = data
}

override fun getCount(): Int {
    return data.myArray.size
}

override fun isViewFromObject(view: View, `object`: Any): Boolean {
    return view == `object`
}

override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int): Any {

    val binding = DataItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), container, false)
    binding.data = data
    binding.executePendingBindings()
    container.addView(binding.root)
    return binding.root
}

override fun getItemPosition(`object`: Any): Int {
    return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE
}

override fun destroyItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int, `object`: Any) {
    container.removeView(`object` as ConstraintLayout)
}}
```

This is the Adapter call in the activity:

```
   override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    val viewPagerAdapter = ViewPagerAdapter(this, data)
    viewPager.adapter = viewPagerAdapter
    viewPager.currentItem = data.myArray.lastIndex
    indicator.setViewPager(viewPager)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your `isViewFromObject` method causes this problem. You should overide it like below:

```
@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return ((Fragment)object).getView() == view;
}
```

Comment: I have changed it but it's still the same!